# What's the best topology for hard surface modeling?

Tags: topology

The one with no subsurf modifier and using a bevel modifier for edge smoothing or the one with subsurf modifier? Because I hate the way subsurf modifier adding a useless edge loop in a flat surfaces and it is much harder to create a hole in it. So I'm asking any tip for this type of modeling?[image: with subsurf modifier][image: without subsurf modifier]

Comment: It is personal opinion and may vary for project requirements but I opt for Smooth shading with Auto Smooth enabled at 30 degrees and then use Bevel modifiers.